# how can I call class method by using objc_class variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface SomeClass
- (void)funcA;
+ (void)funcB;
@end

@interface Test
@property(nonatomic, assign) Class aClass;
@end

@implementation Test
- (void) test {
    // that's ok
    [[aClass new] funcA];
    // but how to call class method?
    [aClass funcB] ?
}
@end
```

XCode note "Instance method 'function' is being used on 'Class' which is not in the root class"

Comment: have you tried `[SomeClass funcB]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
[[aClass class] performSelector:@selector(funcB)];
```

Comment: I found out because ‘funcB’‘s return value is seen as id but there need a CGFloat

Answer (score 1):

```
[((id)aClass) funcB];
```

or similarly to @Pancho's answer

```
[[aClass class] funcB];
```